# How to push new key/value pair into external json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have an external JSON file in the format `{"abcd":[0,0,0],"bfff":[1,2,3]}`. I am able to access the values using `extfile[abcd] or extfile[bfff]`. Now how do I add a new key/value pair like `"ghffh":[4,5,6]` into the external JSON file. I'm using express js with node.

Comment: You figure out how to read and write to files, then you figure out how to parse and stringify JSON, then you figure out how to add a new property to an object, then you put it all together and make it work !

Comment: ... then you figure out how to make unhelpful comments on the internet?

Comment: @RobertLevy: I think showing how to approach a problem (dividing it into subproblems and solve those) is helpful.

Comment: True but you didn't show how to solve any of the sun problems, thus not really helpful